# Обработчик нажатия для кастомного ListView

Tags: android

```
package com.lesson;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Lesson extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lesson);

        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemlist);
        ArrayList<Manager> arraydir = new ArrayList<Manager>();
        Manager manager;

        Resources res = getResources();

        // Вводим данные
        manager = new Manager(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.lesson1), res.getString(R.string.lesson1), res.getString(R.string.lessonname1));
        arraydir.add(manager);
        manager = new Manager(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.lesson2), res.getString(R.string.lesson2), res.getString(R.string.lessonname2));
        arraydir.add(manager);
        manager = new Manager(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.lesson3), res.getString(R.string.lesson3), res.getString(R.string.lessonname3));
        arraydir.add(manager);
        manager = new Manager(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.lesson4), res.getString(R.string.lesson4), res.getString(R.string.lessonname4));
        arraydir.add(manager);

        AdapterLesson adapter = new AdapterLesson(this, arraydir);

        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked.findViewById(R.id.lessonname);
            String strText = textView.getText().toString();

            if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.lesson1))) {
                // Launch the lesson1 Activity
                startActivity(new Intent(Lesson.this, Lesson1.class));

            }

        }
    });

}
```

Как можно сделать обработчик нажатия по item списка чтобы перейти на другой класс с помощmю Intent. То есть нужно чтобы по клику на соответсвующий элемент листвью переходить на соответсвующий класс.

Адаптер

```
package com.lesson;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AdapterLesson extends BaseAdapter{

    protected Activity activity;
    protected ArrayList<Manager> items;

    public AdapterLesson(Activity activity, ArrayList<Manager> items) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
      }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return items.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return items.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Создаем convertView для эффективности
        View v = convertView;

        //Связываем формат списка, который мы создали
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inf.inflate(R.layout.itemlist, null);
        }

        // Создаем объект директивы
        Manager dir = items.get(position);
        //Вводим фото
        ImageView foto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.foto);
        foto.setImageDrawable(dir.getFoto());
        //Вводим номер урока
        TextView lessonnumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lessonnumber);
        lessonnumber.setText(dir.getLessonnumber());
        //Вводим название урока
        TextView lessonname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lessonname);
        lessonname.setText(dir.getLessonname());

        // Возвращаем
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {

       TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked; //Тут дебагер выдает ошибку!!!!
                String strText = textView.getText().toString();

                if (strText.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.lessonname1))) {
                    // Launch the lessonname1 Activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(Lesson.this, Lesson1.class));

Comment: Очевидно, что в `getView` адаптера вы возвращаете вовсе не `TextView`, а `view` другого типа. В общем-то, об этом вам вполне чётко должно сообщать имя возникающего исключения — `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Так покажите же код метода `getView` вашего адаптера. У меня правда всё очень плохо с телепатией.

Comment: Поскольку из адаптера вы возвращаете `ViewGroup`, то для поиска в нём нужного вам `TextView` используйте `findViewById()` у `view` соответствующего элемента списка.

Comment: Не получается, не знаю как правильно это записать...

Comment: Замените в `onItemClick()`

    TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked;

на

    TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked.findViewById(R.id.something);

Comment: В результате ошибок нет, но при нажатии ничего не происходит...